# JQUERY Copy color link and use it in link page

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

how I can copy color value from a colorful menu and use it in new page with Jquery?

```
<a href="page1.php" style="color:#ffcc00">Link1</a>
<a href="page2.php" style="color:#ff0000">Link2</a>
<a href="page3.php" style="color:#00ffff">Link3</a>
```

page1 > #ffcc00 background
page2 > #ff0000 background
page3 > #00ffff background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would require more than just jQuery as all variables are reset once the page is relocated. You could use a `$.cookie` to store the value of the color, or a php `GET` variable to pass that information to the newly loaded page. You could however use jQuery's `.css` method to capture the color and then store it in the `GET` variable or cookie.

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    var color = $(this).css('color');
    console.log(color);
});
```

More info on cookies: [How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

Hope this helps, and let me know if you have more questions!

Answer (score 0):

Is it what are you wanting?

With this code you get the color of the link clicked:

```
    $("a").click(function(){
      console.log($(this).css('color'));
      return false;
    });
```